# Como sobrescrever o método OnItemSelected de um Spinner?

Tags: android, android-fragment, kotlin

estou tentando sobrescrever o método ***OnItemSelected*** de um **Spinner** no meu **Fragment**, da mesma forma que fiz com o **Button**, mas não está dando certo... Como eu conseguiria o mesmo resultado?

Dentro do OnCreate, o bloco comentado funciona perfeitamente, mas quero dar uma "limpada" nele, pois tenho mais de um spinner neste layout e desse jeito está ficando bem poluído.

**Outra dúvida**: Se possível, alguém poderia me explicar como funciona esse método **OnNothingSelected** e como utilizá-lo de forma mais eficaz?

Na expressão "**if (itemSelecionado != ". . .")**" é porquê o primeiro elemento do meu spinner é uma string com ". . .", pra não deixar nenhum item já selecionado de começo, tem alguma forma melhor de resolver isso?

Meu código é o seguinte:

***Vetarano2.kt***

```
com.mtsa.escudeiro_rpghelper.fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Spinner
import android.widget.Toast
import com.mtsa.escudeiro_rpghelper.R

class Veterano2 : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private lateinit var spinner: Spinner
    private lateinit var button: Button

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val fragView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_veterano2, container, false)


        initViews(fragView)
        initListeners()

        // SPINNER RAÇA
        /*
        spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                val selecionado = parent.getItemAtPosition(position) as String
                Toast.makeText(context, "Opção escolhida: $selecionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {}
        }
        */

        return fragView
    }

    private fun initViews(v: View) {
        spinner = v.findViewById(R.id.spinner2)
        button = v.findViewById(R.id.button2)
    }

    private fun initListeners() {
        spinner.onItemSelectedListener = this
        button.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
        when (view?.id) {
            R.id.spinner2 -> {
                val selecionado = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position) as String
                Toast.makeText(context, "Opção escolhida: $selecionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when (v?.id) {
            R.id.button2 -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, "SALVAR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***fragment_veterano2.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="64dp">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/array_example"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

***arrays_diversos.xml***

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="array_example">
        <item>AAAAA</item>
        <item>BBBBB</item>
        <item>CCCCC</item>
        <item>DDDDD</item>
        <item>EEEEE</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Obrigado, desde já!

EDIT: Editei o código para melhor visualização, mas o problema persiste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri meu erro, era apenas falta de atenção... não tenho que chamar na view e sim no parent u_u

```
override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
        when (parent?.id) {
            R.id.spinner2 -> {
                val selecionado = parent.getItemAtPosition(position) as String
                Toast.makeText(context, "Opção escolhida: $selecionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sobre como setar o `onItemSelectedListener(this)` (como se fosse no java) você faz como o código comentado `onItemSelectedListener = this`

Comment: Fiz a alteração, mas ainda assim não funcionou...